# Fetch objects from core data with the 10 soonest dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have objects in my CoreData database that have a "date" property of type NSDate.  How can I fetch objects with the 10 soonest dates?

This is what I have so far:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest new];
fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([MyManagedObject class]) inManagedObjectContext:self.database.managedObjectContext];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
NSArray *result = [self.database.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest: fetchRequest error: nil];
```

I believe this will give me all my managed objects back in sorted order, but I really only need the 10 most current ones.  How can I do this?  And will it be faster to sort them using an `NSFetchRequest` rather than fetching them all and then sorting them programatically?

Comment: add fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 10. you will get maximum 10 entities for that request.

Answer (score 6):

Sort the records in decending order and us `fetchLimit` to only get the most recent results:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest new];
fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([MyManagedObject class]) 
                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.database.managedObjectContext];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" 
                                                               ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:10];
NSArray *result = [self.database.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                    error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
...
NSArray* tenSoonestElements = [result subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
```

Comment: Is this better than limiting the number that I fetch like Seamus suggested above?

Comment: Profile and test. I'm not sure how it would be that much different, since the request still needs to pull all records to sort them correctly. But profiling will confirm if this is true or not.